# What's the correct way to protect a POST route that receives callbacks from a third party service (that doesn't sign the request.)

Tags: node.js, express, twilio, twilio-api

The popular SMS service Twilio allows the application to receive a status callback for downstream message events after sending an SMS message by calling the Twilio API.

Our application utilizes both basic auth and passport.js to manage users, session and protect routes.

What's the correct way to protect the POST route that receives the status callbacks from Twilio, since these callbacks will not be authenticated or signed?

(In other words, trying to protect the route that receives the POST from Twilio on callback currently returns a 401. Removing the authentication obviously allows the request to be received and processed, but leaves the route unprotected.)

Answer (score 0):

This webhook will definitely need to be a public endpoint. Usually for webhooks you will get a signed header that will enable you to verify that the message is legit.

If this is not the case, what you can do is to create a middleware that compares the MessageSid that you receive on the callback with the sid that you got when you made the request to generate the sms.

In case the message doesn't have a MessageSid or the MessageSid does not match any on your database you give an unauthorize response.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options detailed here:

[Security](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security)

For Express and validating Twilio Webhooks, there is a good blog below.

[How to secure Twilio webhook URLs in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-secure-twilio-webhook-urls-in-nodejs)